# How does the 'Lets Dance' bounty work?

Tags: destiny

[image: Let's Dance Bounty]

So I think we can confidently skip the obvious thing about meleeing enemies. My question is which melee attacks count? Can I use my Arc Blade super to achieve this? How rapid is rapid? Are we talking consequtivly or just within 10 seconds or something?

No matter how hard I try, I've not been able to complete this. I've been trying it on the Moon against Hive Thralls.

Comment: I'm not sure when I actually got it but I'm fairly sure I got it while blade dancing my way through enemies. My assumption is that there is a maximum time between kills that cannot be exceeded (eg each kill must be within two seconds of the last or something) but it may be 7 kills in 10 seconds or something like that. I'm commenting because I have no hard evidence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the first dlc the best location is the "Fist of Crota" mission on Earth — after the Sword bearer spawns you can pick up the sword and run to the next area where three packs of thralls attack — plenty enough for a quick melee chain.

Source: Just did it myself after trying several other farming spots.

Comment: This makes the most sense. As the Crota bounties are all about the new Sword, it follows that you should use the sword to melee enemies quickly. In addition a single sword hit can kill multiple enemies.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have seen from youtube and such most people have no longer than 3 seconds between each consecutive kill. It can be achieved whilst in arc blade aswell.

As for time between kills? It's a rough estimate as only seen people achieve with kills in a 3 second window consecutively but to narrow down a hard factual number would be difficult I imagine unless Bungie suddenly announce it or some serious testing! :P

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go for kill a blade of crota mob on the moon and take his sword, then run around smashing groups.

From IGN:-

> The Blades of Crota have invaded this world.
>
> Once this notification pops in, a Hallowed Hive Knight will appear bearing the sword. Kill this powerful enemy to claim the sword as your own.

You can also pick up the award hunt the [Blades of Crota](http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Blades_of_Crota):

> kill 3 Hive Knights that are holding Blade's Sword (The sword you can pick up after you kill them) on Earth and Moon.

Best place to do this is outside of the [Jovian Complex near Skywatch](http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Old_Russia,_Earth#Map)

Answer (score 0):

Rapid melee attacks also work on The Dark Beyond story mission. After the cutscene, the doors open, where the hive rush you in a decent size group. This has worked for the bounty for all of my characters, titan, warlock,and hunter